# Error message in cgwatcher with intel hd graphics 4000

Tags: cgminer

The error message is :  "the miner path for the active default profile (chemin vers cgminer.exe) does not exist. You must set the miner path before you can start mining. Click the manage profiles button in the settings tab to open the profile manager, where you can edit the profiles miner path".

I am using windows 8 with intel i7.

What can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

You must set the miner path before you can start mining. Click the manage profiles button in the settings tab to open the profile manager, where you can edit the profiles miner path